# Kubernetes - logging broken pod's name and namespace to a file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

Is there a way Kubernetes provides to store the name/namespace or metadata of a broken pod or pods running in a cluster in the exact format I would want i.e. pod-name/deployment-name/namespace

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly need. You are looking for a way to monitor the pods, or a way to get logs why the pod crashed?

Comment: Kubernetes might not have this feature in built. I was trying to find a basic solution to get the pod's metadata (for health check/monitoring)and store it in the format I would want in a specific file ..... this wouldn't be achieved in one step ... I was wondering if there is any preferred solution for this problem.